# Create Eclipse Project Presets

Tags: java, eclipse, project, preset

I like to create plugins for another java-program.

But each time I want to create a new project, I have to go through the same steps over and over again: Implement the jar file to my build path, create a plugin-file with all the necessary information in it and create the package that, every time, has about the same pattern ("org.myname.projectname").

I'm probably way too lazy for asking this, but is there a way in Eclipse to create such a preset that will create all the files, imports and packages for me? Would save me up to 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of an already set-up project and re-use this for other projects. Just import it with a different name.

Comment: Can't believe I couldn't come up with that idea by myself. Thanks mate!